# Left Join 3 tables into ONE in Mysql

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I have 3 tables: Employees, attendanceIn table, attendanceOut 
[image: Database schema]

And My query is

```
SELECT  employees.eno,employees.ename,employees.dept,attendanceIn.attIn AS attIn,
       attendanceOut.attOutAS attout
    FROM  employees
    LEFT JOIN  attendanceIn  ON employees.eno=attendanceIn.eno
    LEFT JOIN  attendanceOut  ON employees.eno=attendanceOut.eno
    WHERE  DATE(attendanceIn.puchtime) LIKE '2016-07-01%'
      AND  attendanceOut.puchtime LIKE '2016-07-01%'
    GROUP BY  eno
    ORDER BY  eno ASC
```

Is there any better way to write the query?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use functions on your columns you are comparing against, as that prevents the query from using any indexes you may have.

Start with this:

```
SELECT employees.eno,employees.ename,employees.dept,attendanceIn.attIn AS attIn,attendanceOut.attOutAS attout
FROM employees 
LEFT JOIN attendanceIn ON employees.eno=attendanceIn.eno 
LEFT JOIN attendanceOut ON employees.eno=attendanceOut.eno
WHERE attendanceIn.puchtime >= '2016-07-01 00:00:00'
AND attendanceIn.puchtime < '2016-07-02 00:00:00'
AND attendanceOut.puchtime >= '2016-07-01 00:00:00' 
AND attendanceOut.puchtime < '2016-07-02 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY eno 
ORDER BY eno ASC
```

If you still need performance improvements, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` statements for all your tables in this query.

Comment: The ` 00:00:00` can be removed without any impact.

Comment: I prefer `x >= '2016-07-01' AND x < '2016-07-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY` -- let the computer compute the ending date.

Comment: @RickJames Good to know, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

That should also work more efficient than Willem solution

```
SELECT employees.eno,employees.ename,employees.dept,attendanceIn.attIn AS attIn,attendanceOut.attOutAS attout
FROM employees 
LEFT JOIN attendanceIn ON employees.eno=attendanceIn.eno 
LEFT JOIN attendanceOut ON employees.eno=attendanceOut.eno
WHERE DATE(attendanceIn.puchtime) = '2016-07-01'
AND DATE(attendanceOut.puchtime) = '2016-07-01' 
GROUP BY eno 
ORDER BY eno ASC
```

Comment: Punch TIme have an important role while calculating attendance. Moreover for companies having employees shifts. So we cannot omit punch time in the query

Comment: Note that you brought back the deficiency that Willem has pointed out: by using functions you effectively disabled the usage of any index available on the punchtime-columns (unless there is a function-based one).